# What are some good books for theoretical physics (specifically quantum mechanics) for a beginner?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, education

I want to read physics axiomatically like a typical math course. I watched some lectures by Frederic Schuller. I liked the teaching style but it was a bit advanced for me as I don't know vector bundle etc. I'm looking for resources of similar sort for Quantum mechanics. What are some good resources to get started? I'm a math major and don't know much physics, but I do know a bit of history of physics.

Comment: Have you tried John M Lee's Manifold introductions? And Brian Hall's Quantum Theory for Mathematicians.

Comment: Griffith Electrodynamics, HC Verma Concept of Physics

Comment: @AgnibhoDutta Griffiths is particularly known for simplicity. It would not be in any way a good fit for this particular question.

Comment: Hi Mayank Jangid. Welcome to Phys.SE. To reopen this post (v2) consider to narrow down the topic.

Comment: Physics is not axiomatic. Only physical theory can be made axiomatic, but then... all physical theory is wrong (just not to the same degree). Quantum theory, in particular, is not even about physics. It's the solution theory of a certain type of equation, which may or may not describe nature, depending on your random choice of Hamiltonian. You won't notice any of that until you read an actual textbook about phenomenology, of course. Real physics, OTOH, is messy. If you want to learn about real physics, then you will have to learn to deal with the mess instead of stuffing it into the closet.

Comment: Can't we consider the fundamental laws as axioms and derive every phenomenon as a theorem upon those axioms. For example, can't we consider Maxwell's laws as axioms and derive every electrical and magnetic phenomena from it? Thanks for help!